# Difference between $HOME and '~' (tilde)?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I had always thought that `$HOME` and `~` were exactly the same and thus could
be used interchangeably. Today, when I tried to install *pylibmc*, a python
binding to memcached, on my shared server the use of `~` gave me error but not
`$HOME`. I would like to reason out why.

*libmemcached* is a requirement for *pylibmc*. I have *libmemcached* installed
under my home directory because I have no root on the server. As a result, to
install *pylibmc*, I need to make sure the installation script knows where to
find *libmemcached*.

When executing `python setup.py install --with-libmemcached=~`, the installation
script runs

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall \
  -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE_ZLIB -I~/include \
  -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _pylibmcmodule.c \
  -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing
```

which gives the errors that *libmemcached* can't be found.

If I change to `--with-libmemcached=$HOME`, the script runs

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall \
  -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DUSE_ZLIB -I/home/waterbotte/include \
  -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _pylibmcmodule.c \
  -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing
```

without any problem. It looks like the problem is that tilde doesn't get resolved. But why?

Comment: I consider tilde to be a command-line convenience. In scripts, `$HOME` should always be used instead.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The shell replaces `~` with the user's home directory (**update**: or perhaps by the home directory of some other user, if `~` is followed by something other than a `/`), but only if it's the first character of a word.

`--with-libmemcached=~` has `~` not in the beginning, so the shell leaves it alone.

Comment: stromberg@aw50 ~ $ echo abc~def
abc~def
stromberg@aw50 ~ $ echo ~def
~def
stromberg@aw50 ~ $ echo def~
def~
stromberg@aw50 ~ $ echo abc${HOME}def
abc/home/strombergdef
stromberg@aw50 ~ $ echo ${HOME}def
/home/strombergdef
stromberg@aw50 ~ $ echo def${HOME}
def/home/stromberg
stromberg@aw50 ~ $

Comment: @user1277476: This is very hard to read. Please see the update.

Comment: Interesting fact to learn. Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks n.m.

Comment: @user1277476 `echo` is a built in shell command, the shell knows if you want to `echo` something, the argument is not referring to a file, since `~` is a built in shell expansion, the shell knows better and won't replace it with your home directory.

Comment: It should be mentioned that there's more to tilde expansion than this. See the bash manual on [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html). For instance, tilde is expanded when used in variable assignment (e.g. `SOME=~`) even though it's not the first character of a word then.

Answer (score 61):

The tilde is part of a [shell expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) (like in bash, csh, zsh, etc). The `$HOME` variable is exportable and can be used independent of a specific shell.

Comment: Does it mean that tilde depends on the shell?

Comment: @Nikhil technically that's true, but I don't know of any shell that doesn't use the tilde in the same way as all the other shells

Answer (score 52):

`~` is expanded ONLY if it is the first character of a word AND it is unquoted

```
$ echo "~"
~
$ echo foo~
foo~
$ echo ~
/home/guest
$ echo ~/foo
/home/guest/foo
```

`~username` is expanded to the `HOME` of the `username`.

```
$ echo ~root
/root
$ echo ~invaliduser
~invaliduser
```

To quote filenames, you should use `$HOME` or quote the suffix

```
$ echo "$HOME/foo bar"
/home/guest/foo bar
$ echo ~/"foo bar"
/home/guest/foo bar
$ echo ~root/"foo bar"
/root/foo bar
```

Note the following from ["POSIX Tilde Expansion"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)

> The pathname resulting from tilde expansion shall be treated as if quoted to prevent it being altered by field splitting and pathname expansion.

Answer (score 12):

The main difference is:

```
cd /tmp
ls "$HOME" #works
ls "~" #nope
```

So, shell expand the ~ only in few situations. In your case, the python script simple got ~ inside the script - not the expaded value.

Answer (score 4):

Run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -H -u root bash<<EOF
echo $HOME
echo ~
EOF
```

Output:

```
/home/my_current_user
/root
```

You can see that `~` gets [**expanded**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) later, by the target shell (run by `root`) while `$HOME` gets [**substituted**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html) by the source shell (run by `my_current_user`)