# Git authentication for perl CGI-Script via .netrc

Tags: git, perl, apache, cgi, .netrc

I've got a little perl-script which attempts to pull from a git repository and then gets some things from git log:

```
 use Git::Repository;
 my $repo = Git::Repository->new(
         git_dir => $git_path,
 );
 $repo->run('pull') || die $!;
 my @commits = $repo->run(log);
 ...
```

For the authentication I have a `.netrc`-file with my credentials in `/home/bla`. This works perfectly when the script is run from the shell. Now I've tried to use this script for a web-application:

```
my $evil_commits = `./list_commits.pl`;
```

When I do this it yields the following error message:

```
[Thu Sep 19 12:50:49 2013] [error] [client <>] fatal: Could not read password: No such device or address at ./list_commits.pl line 45
```

I've already tried to set `$ENV{HOME}` inside the CGI-script but that doesn't help. Any suggestions on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Does your web-app runs with the same user account as the one where `~/.netrc` is?

Comment: Nope, but I can't imagine how that makes any difference, since I changed `$ENV{HOME}` to the right directory and I don't get an error saying `permission denied`. Even `chmod 777` on the `.netrc`-file doesn't change anything. I can hardly imagine that this error is related to the user running the script.

Comment: I would say, it does make the difference.

Comment: Could you please also explain why this exact error could be caused by the fact that the users are different instead of just stating, that it 'does make the difference'? And maybe even providing a solution other than "change the user", because that's not possible for me as I don't have administration privileges on the machine.

Comment: I suspect the `curl` library (ultimately called by a `git pull`) which relies on `netrc` for credential **looks for it in `~/.netrc`, not in `$HOME/.netrc`** (and [the two can be different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660054/6309)). I don't have a solution just now, though.

Comment: That indeed sounds reasonable. I didn't know that `$HOME != ~`...

Comment: The [difference is also illustrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11587343/6309).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to print the current directory from withhin the script. That way you will be able to change the path in a way that makes it pointing to the corrent file.

---

Apart from that, i recommend you using ssh-keys. You won't need any password files in that case.

Comment: Both scripts are in the same directory, so that's not the problem. The `list_commits.pl`-script is ran and dies because of the `$repo->run('pull') || die $!;`.