# Installing Boost libraries to a custom directory in ~ (home)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I'm trying to build the boost libraries

as i see at the manual from,

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install

As described at the manual, I'm running the command,

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=path/to/installation/prefix
```

with --prefix=~/boost-libs, like this,

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=~/boost-libs
```

so the libs to be placed in my home directory.

After that I'm running,

```
./b2 install
```

I'm also tried to run it like this,

```
./b2 install --prefix=~/boost-libs
```

But nothing to be placed at 'boost-libs' in my home folder.

- The folder 'boost-libs' is exists in my home folder.

I also tried to run,

```
$ sudo ./bootstrap.sh
```

and then

```
$ sudo ./b2 install
```

so the installation will go to '/usr/local/lib', and it **does** work,
but not succeeded to install to a custom directory.

Thanks

Comment: _"But nothing to be placed at 'boost-libs' in my home folder."_ Where **is** it placed? Does the output of `install` show anything about what it does? Does anything change if you replace `~` with `$HOME`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $HOME and '~' (tilde)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587343/difference-between-home-and-tilde) because your `~` is not at the start of its word (which is the `-` of the switch), so it shouldn't get expanded by the shell, so that command should just end up installing to a folder called `~` in your current working directory.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with $HOME like this,
./b2 install --prefix=$HOME/boost-libs;
and it run OK.
@underscore_d

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments above,

Running it using $HOME instead of '~/' solved the problem,

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$HOME/boost-libs
```

Thanks

For more details about $HOME and '~/' at that link,

[Difference between $HOME and '~' (tilde)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587343/difference-between-home-and-tilde)