# "No such file or directory" error while installing boost on Red Hat OS

Tags: boost, error-handling, build, caffe

While installing `caffe` on SLURM cluster with Red Hat OS, I get the following error:

```
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/clip_layer.o] Error 1
In file included from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/layers/concat_layer.hpp:6,
                 from src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.cu:3:
./include/caffe/common.hpp:4:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

It seems I do not have the `boost` installed on my account/machine as I checked `/usr/include`! (This is a university cluster and users do not have installation privilege).

My question is how to install `boost` on Red Hat OS considering such circumstances?

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  440.64.00  Wed Feb 26 16:26:08 UTC 2020
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the source of boost for the version you want. 
https://www.boost.org/users/download/

Configure it using your home directory as the Prefix as described in
[Installing Boost libraries to a custom directory in ~ (home)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208047/installing-boost-libraries-to-a-custom-directory-in-home)

Answer (score 0):

While tomgalpin's answer seems completely right, I just provide the commands summary:

Download the latest boost package from [here](https://www.boost.org/users/download/) or simply get it in terminal:

```
$ wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.72.0/source/boost_1_72_0.tar.gz
```

Following this [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install):

```
$ cd path/to/boost_1_72_0 # or your own version
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=path/to/custom_folder
$ /b2 install --prefix=path/to/custom_folder
```

When done, `$ cd path/to/custom_folder` and `$ ls` will show you `include` and `lib` folders created in `custom_folder`